# AngularJS 2-way binding with TaffyDB

Tags: angularjs, 2-way-object-databinding, taffydb

I can't seem to get the scope variables display on the html particularly $scope.r. I can only get scope variables through ng-repeat but not individually. The $scope.r is a pure js object retrieved from [TaffyDB record object](http://www.taffydb.com/).  I also can get values from the ng-model object within the html but not scope variables from the javascript file not being used within the ng-repeat directive. Am I doing anything wrong?

```html
<script src="https://github.com/typicaljoe/taffydb/raw/master/taffy.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

          <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
          <span class="input-label">Definition</span>
          <input ng-model="def" ng-value="{{r.defn}}" type="text" placeholder="New Definition ">
      </label>
      <label class="item">
        <span>English Translation</span>
    </label>
    <label class="item item-input">
        <textarea placeholder="English Meaning">
            {{r.etrans}}{{r.defn}}
            {{def.length}}{{def.charAt(0)}}  
            {{wdc({ch:def.charAt(0)}).first().allch}}{{wdc({ch:def.charAt(0)}).count()}}
        </textarea>
    </label>
```

Here's the javascript

```javascript
var defs = TAFFY([]);
var emptydb=false;
defs.store('wdic');

.controller('ListController', ['$scope', '$http', '$state', '$location',
    function($scope, $http, $state,$location) {
    $http.get('js/wdc.json').success(function(data) {
      $scope.wdc2 = TAFFY(data);
      $scope.whichartist=$state.params.aId;
      $scope.data = { showDelete: false, showReorder: false };
      $scope.defs=defs;
      $scope.r =$scope.defs({___id:$state.params.aId}).first();
      $scope.defs().each(function (r) {console.log(r.defn+'~'+r.___id)});
      console.log("here"+$scope.r.etrans);
      $scope.addurl ="#/tab/list/add";
      $scope.wdc=TAFFY([
        {
          "id": 1,
          "ch": "a",
          "basech": "a",
          "allch": "a,ā,á,à"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "ch": "à",
          "basech": "a",
          "allch": "a,ā,á,à"
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "ch": "ā",
          "basech": "a",
          "allch": "a,ā,á,à"
        },
        {
          "id": 4,
          "ch": "á",
          "basech": "a",
          "allch": "a,ā,á,à"
        }
      ]);      
    });
}]);
```

Comment: i wonder how are u binding data to textarea.It should be like 
`<textarea
  ng-model="string"
</textarea>`

Comment: That's the thing some of the scope variables display (wdic) display while other (r) doesn't.

Comment: Are u sure `r` has etrans and defn properties ?

Comment: sure!  That's why I had to console.log the $scope.r.etrans variable to make double sure.  And they actually work when I use them on another page inside the ng-repeat.  But let me see if I can use the filter trick to forcefully display it, which I was trying to avoid.